# How can I get the device name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm developing an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

I want to get the device name using code lines.

Any one have an idea on this ?

**Note :** I'm working with VS2008 using C# on win7.

Comment: Is this device connected through USB?

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516(v=vs.80).aspx You may also want to check out the product page. There is an SDK available: http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=&cat=&pid=Dolphin6100&rank=&=

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string IDENTITY = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Ident";
private const string NAME = "Name";  

string DeviceName = (string)Registry.GetValue(IDENTITY, NAME, "NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

We developed an application for the same device, we used this sentense to get device name.

```
Private Sub deviceidt_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles deviceidt.ParentChanged
        Dim deviceidn As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
        deviceidt.Text = deviceidn
        End If
    End Sub
```